# Action link is not passing value to value to controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following MVC controller action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SelectMember(int memberId = 0, String returnUrl = "")
{
    if (memberId > 0)
    {
        /* Save selected member id ... */

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            return RedirectPermanent(returnUrl);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

I'm using the given link:

> localhost:61286/Builder/SelectMember?memberId=1&returnUrl=%2FBuilder%2FSelectArea

But when `SelectMember` is called using this link, the `memberId` is always 0. `returnUrl` is correct.

Here is the associated razor view:

```
@using MyApp.Web.Languages
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Web.Models.Member>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Builder.SelectMemberTitle;
}

<h2>@Builder.SelectMemberTitle</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(Builder.SelectButton, "SelectMember", new { memberId = item.MemberId, returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Here is my route configuration:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Categorized",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{category}/{id}",
            defaults: new { }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you not using the `Route` attribute? Or a general routing somewhere?

Comment: I do occasionally use Route attributes but not here. I will add my route configuration to my post.

Comment: I can't see a route that would take `memberId` and `returnUrl` in your code. Maybe you could add a `Route` attribute for this `Action`?

Comment: After some lengthy debugging, I have determined that the problem has to do with a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` I wrote. This filter only redirects to `SelectMember` so I can't figure out how it could possibly be involved, but it is. The action that it decorates is randomly called when I link to `SelectMember`.  Here is a link to my question on the matter: http://goo.gl/N2D1P7

Comment: You posted another question that's related to this one. Aren't they on the same subject?

Comment: Try using `memberId` instead of `memberId=0`.

Comment: I did try this. Please see: goo.gl/N2D1P7 .

Comment: I was using `RedirectPermanent` which apparently does something completely different then I intended.